# How can I implement a 'select all' check-box on my CRM 4 custom form?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-4

I am working on a custom CRM form with numerous checkboxes, organized by sections.  I would like to implement a 'select all' feature to the form and am trying to understand how to format the JavaScript.  My research thus far has pointed me to the possibility of using a FOR statement to iterate through all of the elements in the section I want to process, setting their values accordingly, but am unsure of which document.getElements ... method to utilize.

Here is an existing SO question related to the FOR iteration I mention above:

[How do I get all elements of a particular HTML tag in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842710/how-do-i-get-all-elements-of-a-particular-type-in-javascript)

I'm not sure I know what Tag Name I need to reference for my fields, using that method.  They are of type BIT, is that the same as the Tag Name?  I have exported the entity's customization file and have access to the class ID for the group of fields, is there a method I could use, passing that data?

Answer (score 0):

in your crm form select change proterties for the 'select all' checkbox and add the following to the on change method

```
crmForm.all.[one of my checkboxen].DataValue = crmform.all.[my select all box].DataValue;
```

replace [one of my checkboxen] with the name of a checkbox (probably new_something) and [my select all box] with the name of your select all box.

add one line for each checkbox you want to control.

this is not an ideal solution as you have to keep updating the code everytime you add ot remove a check box but it has the adaventage that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out; by utilizing the DOM through JavaScript, I was able to iterate through the checkbox items in my form section.

```
var section = document.getElementById("{5d86cfd1-4612-e211-8c63-0015c5f7fc75}");
var fields = section.getElementsByTagName("input");

if (crmForm.all.tmi_selectallwtm.DataValue == true) {
    for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (fields[i].className == "ms-crm-CheckBox") {
            fields[i].DataValue = true;
        }//end IF
        else {}

    }//end FOR
}//end IF
else {
    for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (fields[i].className == "ms-crm-CheckBox") {
            fields[i].DataValue = false;
        }//end IF
        else {}
    }//end FOR
}//end ELSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var section = document.getElementById('a');
var fields = section.getElementsByTagName("input");


    for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {

            fields[i].checked= true;


    }
```

Comment: Care to add some comments? Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.